# Metrics to measure the contribution of moving objects to increasing/reducing their separation distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

At time $t_0$, two objects are located on a 2D plane. Each object moves in a straight line and at time $t_1$, both are located at new positions, and thus may be closer or further to each other than they were at $t_0$.

I would like to estimate the contribution of the movement of each object to having increased (or reduced) the separation distance, but I can't get my head around what would be an appropriate metric. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Google the 'distance formula'

Comment: I know how to calculate the distance between two objects. I am interested in measuring to what extent changes in this distance over time, when objects are moving, are caused by object 1 or object 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but hopefully it helps you.

One can easily compute the distance (Pythagoras) and the rate at which the distance changes (i.e., the derivative). When doing that, you'll see that this only depends or the relative position and relative velocity. Hence, it does not make sense to estimate the contribution of the movement of a single object to the changing distance.

Comment: Thanks, using 'rate of change' indeed got me started, and I will pursue this. I am however surprised: assume that object 1 did not move, and that object 2 reach its position, can't we say that object 2 did 100% of the reduction in distance? Assuming that both objects have moved towards the other, and have met at midpoint, can't we say that each contributed 50% of the reduction in distance? Is this valid only because in these examples I am assuming a 1D?

Comment: In your example, the distance became smaller because object 1 did not move and object 2 did move into the direction of object 1. That is, if object 1 did move, the distance could have been larger, so should we then say that object 1 also contributed because it did not move? In my humble opinion, it makes no sense to quantify which object contributed to what extent. And, as mentioned in the answer, as the rate at which the distance changes only depends on relative distance and relative velocity, I also can't get my head around what would be an appropriate measure ;)

Comment: Underlying that the fact that object 1 did not move is actually a contribution clarifies everything. Thanks for having followed up.